# Matching of two weighted graphs allowing one-to-many mapping

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, heuristics

I am looking for a heuristic for a graph matching problem as follows.

Given two graphs: $A$ (consisting of nodes $a_i$) and $B$ (consisting of nodes $b_i$). Typically the size of $B$ is larger than that of $A$.

Each node and edge in two graphs has weight. The task is to match graph $A$ to graph $B$, *i.e*., find a set of nodes and links in $B$ to map each node and link of $A$, such as the host node/link in $B$ has larger weight than the corresponding node/link of $A$.

The following figure illustrates two possible cases (or solution) of mapping (matching):

- **Case 1**: One-to-one mapping: Each node or edge of $A$ needs only one node or link of $B$ to map. Here the nodes $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are mapped on to $b_1, b_2, b_3$, and the edges $a_1a_2, a_2a_3$ are mapped onto $b_1b_2$ and $b_2b_3$ respectively.

  - Constraints are satisfied: For nodes: $b_1 > a_1$, $b_2 > a_2$, $b_3 > a_3$. For edges: $b_1b_2 > a_1a_2$ and $b_2b_3 > a_2a_3$.
- **Case 2**: One-to-many mapping: One needs more than 1 node/edge of $B$ to host a node/edge of $A$. In the example, $a_1$ is mapped on to $b_1$ and $b_4$, $a_2, a_3$ are mapped onto $b_2, b_3$. For the edges: $a_1a_2$ is mapped onto $b_1b_2$ and $b_4b_2$, and $a_2a_3$ is mapped onto $b_2b_3$.

  - Constraints are satisfied: For nodes: $b_1 + b_4 = 11 > a_1$, $b_2 > a_2$, $b_3 > a_3$. For edges: $b_1b_2 + b_4b_2 = 8 > a_1a_2$ and $b_2b_3 > a_2a_3$.

Heuristics for Case 1 have been well studied, *e.g*., using *eigendecomposition* to solve the *Weighted Graph Matching Problem* ([WGMP](http://www.indiana.edu/~pcl/rgoldsto/papers/weighted%20graph%20match2.pdf)). Nevertheless, I could not find an appropriate algorithm to find a solution as in Case 2. Any suggestions?

[image: Example figure]

Comment: (I added your figure.) $b_1 + b_2 = 11$: Did you mean $12$? Or did you mean $b_1 + b_4 = 11$?

Comment: Thanks @JosephO'Rourke, I meant $b_1 + b_4 = 11$. I edited the question.